# Creating GTK+ themes

Tags: linux, gnome, themes, gtk, xfce

Are there any good software for designing, or helping in designing, GTK+ themes for use in Gnome and Xfce desktops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any such software. I think it has to be done "by hand". Try this [link.](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is an old one, but I happened upon an answer for this, so I thought I'd share. [oomox](https://github.com/themix-project/oomox) seems to be the best way to do this, short of doing it by hand (which I'm sure is a learning experience worth trying, but this tool makes it easy)

To quote the description in their README:

> Graphical application for generating different color variations of Oomox (Numix-based), Materia (ex-Flat-Plat) and Arc themes (GTK2, GTK3, Cinnamon, GNOME, Openbox, Xfwm), Archdroid, Gnome-Color, Numix, Papirus and Suru++ icon themes. Have a hack for HiDPI in gtk2.

It also seems to be compatible with most Linux distros and most DEs.

Comment: It does indeed work with cinnamon, gnome, xfce/xfwm, metacity, and more and makes gtk2/3 and 3.2 consistent themes. It is not easy for everyone to get installed, but works like a champ in MX Linux I know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find one either.

There's **[GNOME Color Chooser](https://launchpad.net/gnome-color-chooser)**, which may help.

[image: GNOME Color Chooser]

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but if you have the patience you could wait for the new theme solution based on CSS to complete. More information [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/theming/2009/08/12/announcing-gtk-css-engine-031/).

Answer (score 0):

One method which I found to be not so bad is to take a theme and modify the gtkrc file.

e.g. `/usr/share/themes/MurrinaStormCloud/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

You'll have to experiment and do a lot of guessing and trial-and-error, but it worked for me. All I really wanted was to make that theme less gray-ish and a bit more silver-ish and blue-ish.